# Morphable field not working for Laravel DB::Select() statement

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to use DB::select() statement for a complex query I´m working on that is not returning any results. After some diggin I found out the reason was that the **model_type** field comparison was not working regardless wheather I use this sintaxis:

```
select *
from questions
where model_type = "App\Models\Product"
```

Or this sintaxis:

```
select * 
from questions
where model_type = "App\\Models\\Product"
```

Even though the second sentence works perfectly on MySQL Workbench, it returns no results in Laravel.
The MySQL table field name is of course **model_type** and the values are hold as: **App\Models\Product** and all relationships work perfectly. It seems that there should be a way to specify to Laravel how to compare the values, but I haven´t found it.
Please note that I have to use DB::select() as oposed to Eloquent, since my actual query deals with MySQL MATCH() AGAINST() and some other complexities.

Any help would be welcome. Txs!

Comment: can you provide a [mre] with concrete example

Comment: @nbk yes, is the one I have described. Just setup any morpheable model in a table and try to select * from your_table where model_type = "App\\Models\\YourModel" using DB::select(). It works fine in MySQL, but doesn´t work on Laravel... at least not for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else runs into this predicament, I still don´t know why Eloquent is not able to resolve it´s model, but I did find this great article which solves this and other potential situations as well, by decoupling Laravel logic from the information stored in the database. https://josephsilber.com/posts/2018/07/02/eloquent-polymorphic-relations-morph-map#the-default-morph-type